# is there a deference between 6.5 and 6.0 vcenter when we use REST API

Tags: rest, api, vsphere

I am getting this error when I try to get list or to create VM
[image]

Comment: Please post error messages and code embedded in your question instead of pasting links. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the REST interface doesn't exist in 6.0 to manage VMs. That was an interface which was added to vSphere 6.5 and newer versions.